# graphing a bind9 query.log

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind

I would really like to start taking advantage of the query.log we are keeping on our caching name servers. I go through it by hand on occasion looking for anomalies or customers going crazy with heartbeat/keep alive lookups. There is so much info in this file and I'd like to be able to process it and graph it to show things like top domain lookups, top users of our DNS based on our IP ranges. Pretty charts and graphs for executives would be nice ;) We are already doing graphs on queries per second and a few others using bindgraph but I'd like more.

Does anyone know of any good, open source/non-commercial solutions to this? I know cricket, rrdtool and a few others could do it but writing the code to parse and graph the info isn't an option right now.  Any other ideas I'm not thinking of to get info from these machines?

Answer (score 2):

I use [DSC](http://dns.measurement-factory.com/tools/dsc/) for monitoring multiple DNS servers. It's slightly awkward to setup, but provides a LOT of data.